# Update an array from another component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-components

I'm using two angular components:
Component A:
I send the result of an http call to the component "appComponent" (response is an array of objects)

```
this.appComponent.updateList(response);
```

In the AppComponent:

```
  updateList(arrayOfNewValues) {
    this.list = arrayOfNewValues;
  }

trackByFn(index, item) { return index; }
```

The list is updated correctly but the *ngFor in the appComponent view cannot detect the changes:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; trackBy: trackByFn"></div>
```

Changes are detected only if I update the list with new data inside the appComponent.
If I try to update the list from another component changes are not detected

Comment: Is it possible you could show the code of both components? Are you using a service to provide data to the appComponent? It sounds like you're calling the appComponent's updateList method directly, but I think you may want to inject a service into the appComponent

Comment: It sounds like you have one component that directly references another component, which is not the best/recommended way to share data between components. Take a look at [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) for a variety of ways that are recommended for components to share data. One of them should fit your needs.

Comment: @Dream_Cap  I'm calling the appComponent's updateList method directly

Comment: City33, an array only "change" if use a push, pop or add and element, not if you change a propertie of an element of the array. (an array is only a memory position and a length) you can make some like this.myarray=[].concat(this.myarray) or some similar depending your requeriments

Comment: @Eliseo unfortunately  `this.myarray=[].concat(this.myarray)` as well as
 `this.myArray.push(newItem);
this.myArray = this.myArray.slice(); `
 don't trigger change.

`<component-template [list]="list"></component-template>` works but it render the html of the component-template inside the view of the element where i put into